# Is it safe to call across CRT boundaries using COM?

Tags: c++, com, msvcrt

We are in the process of upgrading our compiler from Visual Studion 2010 (MSVC 10) to VS2013 (MSVC 12). Obviously, this involves a change in CRT version; and inevitably it also involves finding third-party libraries that don't have a VS2013 version available.

I have read up on the dangers of passing objects across the boundary between different CRTs, but most of the third-party libraries I mentioned are exposed to us over COM.

Is it always, never, or sometimes safe to call across a CRT boundary using COM? If "sometimes", what governs whether it's safe?

Comment: Marking my own Q as a possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3187640/crt-types-across-process-boundaries, because I'm actually not sure whether it answers my question or not...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is important here is what calls are actually in question. If objects are talking one to another via COM interfaces, then it is safe to mix them in any combination. It is the same COM in older and newer modules. The problem only arises when you do CRT calls, and one module is manipulating with objects that belong to a different CRT version, e.g. `new` in one module and then `delete` in another. You don't have this problem when you pass COM pointers and call COM methods.

Comment: Then I think we are safe? Across a COM boundary, we only call COM methods. We pass builtins (`long` etc.), COM objects via `IObject*`, enums, `VARIANT`s (especially `VARIANT_BOOL`), and `BSTR`s. I don't _believe_ we pass anything else.

Comment: Yes, you should be fine